# How do I change a calculation based on a drop down box?

Tags: javascript, calculator

Disclaimer for possible question ignorance - I am super super green at coding Javascript and I'm looking for some friendly advice.

I am looking to code a very basic calculator for a website. This calculator works out a very simple calculation for heat output requirements for a room based on size. But I want the calculation to alter slightly based on a user selected drop down option, namely if the user wants to input in meters or feet.

Code is (currently) as follows:

```js
    function Calculate() {
      var a = document.getElementById("height").value;
      var b = document.getElementById("width").value;
      var c = document.getElementById("depth").value;
      var d = +a * +b * +c / 14;
      var x = d.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
    }
```

```html
<form style="width:100px;" name="myForm">
  <td>
    <td>Units:</td>
    <td>
      <Select name="units">
        <option>Metres</option>
        <option>Feet</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
</form>

<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">Height:</td>
      <td>
        <input style="width:100px;" type="text" name="Height" id="height">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">Width:</td>
      <td>
        <input style="width:100px;" type="text" name="Width" id="width">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">Depth:</td>
      <td>
        <input style="width:100px;" type="text" name="Depth" id="depth">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <br>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">
        <input type="button" onclick="Calculate()" value="Calculate" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">Heat output required in kW:</td>
      <td>
        <p id="result"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I'm basically looking for the drop down box to change the calculation in 'var d' from the stated calculation to 
`((+a * +b * +c) *0.03) /14`

It's as simple as that. I've read various threads but they don't all seem to quite explain what I'm after.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) or did you just abbreviate JavaScript?

Comment: Told you I was green haha. Yes, javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give your select an `id` then query your select and get the selected option's text. If it's 'Metres' do it one way otherwise do it the other way, like so:

```js
function Calculate() {
  var s = document.getElementById("units");
  var measure = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
  
  var a = document.getElementById("height").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("width").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("depth").value;
  var d;
  if(measure=="Metres")
    d = +a * +b * +c / 14;
  else
    d = ((+a * +b * +c) *0.03) /14;
  var x = d.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<form style="width:100px;" name="myForm">
  <td>
    <td>Units:</td>
    <td>
      <Select name="units" id="units">
        <option>Metres</option>
        <option>Feet</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
</form>

<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">Height:</td>
      <td>
        <input style="width:100px;" type="text" name="Height" id="height">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">Width:</td>
      <td>
        <input style="width:100px;" type="text" name="Width" id="width">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">Depth:</td>
      <td>
        <input style="width:100px;" type="text" name="Depth" id="depth">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <br>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">
        <input type="button" onclick="Calculate()" value="Calculate" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;">Heat output required in kW:</td>
      <td>
        <p id="result"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: This is great. I have a better understanding now of how it should work. Is there any reason this amended code wouldn't work on jsfiddle? I was using it to style the form etc. I clicked calculate and it didn't work. See the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/p15xcf57/

Comment: you need to click the javascript (upper right of the js area) and select 'No wrap' then click run again, it should work after that